# What's the most efficient conversion of Components to Credits?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

I have a big pile of components that I've acquired from disassembling various items that would otherwise sell to vendors for very small sums of money. At the point in the game that I'm at, in the short term, I need credits more than I need components; I've just RNG'd up a shop with some of the best gear in the game, but it's going to cost me 50,000 creds I don't have, whereas I'm pretty much set for upgrades until I can work on skills quite a bit more.

What items can I build that will yield the highest sell-to-vendor price *per component* to construct them?

(If it matters, I am playing with TSLCRM, but I don't think it makes any notable changes to the crafting system or item pricing.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you are in the story you should go to **[Geeda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Geeda_(Nar_Shaddaa))**, a Rodian trader on **Nar Shaddaa**, to buy/sell stuff.

If you are on the light side and did not finished the quests, **Akkere (Dantooine)** can buy/sell things from you for a better price if you don't turn him in.

I think there are more quest related things to improve the relationship with merchants (like Oondar and Geeda fight).

About the **components**, I don't know the breakdown for each one but I believe one easy way to go is the **Mild Devaronian Edge**. You can build it with **one component** and it worth around **24 credits**.

As far as I know TSLCRM don't mess with the prices, but it fix some bugs and exploits.

> Sources:
>
> [strategywiki](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_melee#Devaronian_Edge)
>
> [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kotor/comments/4e8jv2/best_store_in_kotor_2/)
>
> [reddit2](https://www.reddit.com/r/kotor/comments/4jhx4l/infinite_moneycomponentchemical_source_found/)

Comment: On an unrelated note, the easiest way to make some fast credits in the game, probably, is the swoop race and pazaak (save, practice a little and them for the real thing).